# How to increase the size of progress bar in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, alignment

1. I am designing a UI in Javafx Some issue with progressbar component.
        I want the size of the progress bar to fit in window size in the below example.can any one help to align this.

[Click her for UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTBEV.png)

import java.util.Random;

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class SampleCode extends Application {

        Label l1 = new Label("Loading channel(s) details from NE... ");
        Label l2 = new Label("Please wait...");
        public final static String cssFilePath = "MainPage.css";

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 50);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("1830 PSS-APA");
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource(cssFilePath).toExternalForm());
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();

            scene.setRoot(grid);

            Image nokiaIconImg = new Image(SampleCode.class.getResource("nokiaicon.jpg").toExternalForm());

            grid.getChildren().add(l1);
            GridPane.setConstraints(l2, 0, 2);
            GridPane.setColumnSpan(l2, 3);
            grid.getChildren().add(l2);

            ProgressBar p2 = new ProgressBar();

            grid.getChildren().add(p2);
            GridPane.setConstraints(p2, 0, 4);
            GridPane.setColumnSpan(p2, 4);

            stage.getIcons().add(nokiaIconImg);

            stage.show();

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: p2.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth());